How to get a text file from javascript
I have a txt file, like this:
Test 1  "SCH4U , BSK4U1"    test1@gmail.com 12  9:00 - 12:00
Test 2  MPH4U   test2@gmaiL.com 10  10:00 - 12:00
Want to know, how to reference the text file, through code and then display it on the webpage. I am using wordpress for this. I can't use any plugins as the admin does not allow any.
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="file" id="txtFile" accept=".txt" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script>
const filePath = 'https://hwdsbcommons.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/16166/2024/05/testtutor.csv_.txt';
const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
const txtFile = document.getElementById("txtFile");
myForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const input = txtFile.files[0];
  //const input = filePath;
  const reader = new FileReader();
  const i = 0;
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    const text = e.target.result;
    const Text = [];
    Text[i] = text;
    document.write(Text[i]);
    i = i + 1;
  };
  reader.readAsText(input);
});
</script>

That is my current code, but instead of a button, and user input, I need it to do it from a static file path. The file name stays the same but the file is updated from time to time.

What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck? If this is really about replacing the dynamically read file path through a static one, this should not be that hard?

You cannot gain access to a user’s file system from Javascript on a web browser unless you are given access to a file by the user. This is by design.

Here's how to read in a text file...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function OpenTxtFile(e,Path){

if(Path!==''){

 let F=e.files[0], R=new FileReader();

 R.readAsText(F);

 R.onload=function(){

  let Data=this.result;

  alert(Data);  // <--- Process Data here as required

 };

}}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

</script>

<input type="file" id="Open" accept=".txt" onchange="OpenTxtFile(this,this.value); this.value=null;" style="display:none;">

<button onclick="Open.click();" title="Open a txt file">Open Txt</button>

</body>
</html>

